# Is there a verification callback when the sms code is not auto-retrieved?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

```
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber({String phoneNumber,
                                Duration timeout,    
                                int forceResendingToken,
                                void Function(AuthCredential) verificationCompleted,
                                void Function(AuthException) verificationFailed,
                                void Function(String,[int]) codeSent,
                                void Function(String) codeAutoRetrievalTimeout})

... some stuff ...

[verificationCompleted] This callback must be implemented.
It will trigger when an SMS is auto-retrieved or the phone
number has been instantly verified. The callback will receive an
[AuthCredential] that can be passed to
[signInWithCredential] or [linkWithCredential].

... some other stuff ...
```

Reading this, my conclusion is that `verificationCompleted` is **NOT** called when the sms code is **NOT** auto-retrieved. Please correct me if I am wrong. I need a to implement a verification completed callback when the user has to manually enter the OTP. How do I achieve that? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think codeAutoRetrievalTimeout is what you are looking for. This function is called when firebase fails to retrieve the code automatically.

What I suggest you to do is,
Implement the codeAutoRetrievalTimeout method like this.

When the function is called:

1. Ask the user to manually input the otp.
2. use phoneAuthProvider to
   verify the OTP and get the credentials:

```
AuthCredential _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                            verificationId: widget.verificationId,
                            smsCode: otp);
_auth.signInWithCredential(_credential).then((value) {
    resolveUser(context, value.user);
}).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
});
```

Comment: That's indeed the correct flow. See the documentation for `onCodeSent` in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks

Comment: Thank you Goutam for helping me with this. I had already implemented `codeAutoRetrievalTimeout`. What I needed to do was to stop at the point where I have the user OTP and get the credentials as you suggested above instead of signing in. In fact, as you might have guessed, I was trying to merge the user accounts.